# VectorLayer still empty even if attribute has been set with value

Tags: qgis, layers, features, api, c++

I am working with the QGIS API C++ 2.8.2, my application is written in QT 4.5.3 / C++

I had to create a VectorLayer in memory with attributes and features and export it to a shapefile to import it in QGIS application

So the creation of the VectorLayer works, it is based on the QGIS Python programming cookbook page 56, then  I decide to add attributes and set features.

Here is the code for the attributes:

```
QgsVectorDataProvider * lDataProvider = lVectorLayer->dataProvider();
QDateTime MyTime;
lVectorLayer->startEditing();
// add attribute
QList <QgsField> lMyAttribField;
lMyAttribField << QgsField("Id",QVariant::Int)
<< QgsField("Label",QVariant::String)   
<< QgsField("Type",QVariant::String)    
<< QgsField("Color",QVariant::String)   
<< QgsField("PosX",QVariant::Double)    
<< QgsField("PosY",QVariant::Double)    
<< QgsField("TimeStamp",QVariant::String);  

lDataProvider->addAttributes(lMyAttribField);
```

It is based also on stackexchange sample and cookbook QGIS
Then I set the feature like this:

```
// add feature
QgsFeature MyFeature;
QgsFeatureList MyFeatureList;
MyFeature.initAttributes(7);
MyFeature.setGeometry( QgsGeometry::fromPoint(QgsPoint(QPoint(5.9,43.12))));

for (int i=0; i<2; i++) {
    QgsAttributes MyAttributes;
    MyAttributes << QVariant(0) << QVariant("Test") << QVariant("Neutre") << QVariant("#556677")
    << QVariant(5) << QVariant(43) << QVariant(QString::number(MyTime.toMSecsSinceEpoch()));
    // set the feature with the attributes value
    MyFeature.setAttributes(MyAttributes);
    MyFeature.setFeatureId(i);
    MyFeature.setValid(true);
    // add feature in the list
    MyFeatureList << MyFeature;
}
// add the feature to the dataprovider
lDataProvider->addFeatures(MyFeatureList);
```

then finalise the edition of the VectorLayer and save to a file:

```
// sauvegarde des  attributs
lVectorLayer->commitChanges();
lVectorLayer->updateExtents();
lVectorLayer->updateFields();
// add to the registry
QgsMapLayerRegistry::instance()->addMapLayer(lVectorLayer);

QgsVectorFileWriter * writer;
writer = new QgsVectorFileWriter("/tmp/myshapes.shp",
    "CP1250",lVectorLayer->pendingFields(),
    QGis::WKBPoint,mpMapCanvas->mQgsCoordinate,
    "ESRI Shapefile");

    qDebug() << "Count of feature =" << lVectorLayer->featureCount();
    // insert the vector layer into the vectorlayermap
    mMapLayer.insert(pType, lVectorLayer);
```

When I launch the  application, I load a S57 file, map has been correctly displayed in my canvas ,I have a button to add Track or Layer, when I click on it everything seems to works, file .shp has been created in /tmp.

So I launch QGIS application, I choose Add vector, select my shapefile, the file appears without error in the layer list, when I open the attribute table there is only one field!!!! and no features!!!!!